# setlocale in Cakephp

Tags: php, locale, cakephp-2.0

I have a multilanguage web app in cakephp 2.9 working well with its .po files and all but now I'm I also need to tranlate date & time strings which I know are done by the setlocale function. If I include the setlocale inline in the view file works however when I put it inside my language change function (which I've been using to switch languages since always) it doesn't work.

My languages controller is as follows:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class IdiomasController extends AppController {

    var $uses = array();


    public function idioma_spa($u=null) 
    {

        $this->Session->write('Config.language', 'spa');
        setlocale(LC_TIME, array('es_ES.UTF-8', 'esp'));   


        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }

    public function idioma_eng($u=null) 
    {
        $this->Session->write('Config.language', 'eng');
        setlocale(LC_TIME, array('en_US.UTF-8', 'eng'));   
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }

    public function idioma_ita($u=null) 
    {
        $this->Session->write('Config.language', 'ita');
        setlocale(LC_TIME, array('it_IT.UTF-8', 'ita'));

        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
}
```

And these functions are called in a dropdown in the navbar this way:

```
            <?php if($this->Session->read('Config.language')=='spa'):?>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown navbar-right">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">ES</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo $this->Html->url( array('plugin' => null,'controller'=>'idiomas','action'=>'idioma_eng',$url3)); ?>">EN</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo $this->Html->url( array('plugin' => null,'controller'=>'idiomas','action'=>'idioma_ita',$url3)); ?>">IT</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php elseif($this->Session->read('Config.language')=='eng'):?>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown navbar-right">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">EN</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo $this->Html->url( array('plugin' => null,'controller'=>'idiomas','action'=>'idioma_spa',$url3)); ?>">ES</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo $this->Html->url( array('plugin' => null,'controller'=>'idiomas','action'=>'idioma_ita',$url3)); ?>">IT</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php elseif($this->Session->read('Config.language')=='ita'):?>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown navbar-right">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">IT</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo $this->Html->url( array('plugin' => null,'controller'=>'idiomas','action'=>'idioma_eng',$url3)); ?>">EN</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo $this->Html->url( array('plugin' => null,'controller'=>'idiomas','action'=>'idioma_spa',$url3)); ?>">ES</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Are you using `$this->Session->read('Config.language')` to set the locale anywhere? Calling `setlocale` immediately before redirecting will have no effect on anything; it gets reset to default with every page load.

Comment: Hi, yes I have this line at the top of my layout `Configure::write('Config.language', $this->Session->read('Config.language'));`

Comment: That would be too late, as all controller processing would be done and the view would already have been rendered at that time. Your solution looks like the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

well managed to solve this:

class AppController extends Controller
{
public $components = array('Session');

```
    public function beforeFilter() {
        if ($this->Session->check('Config.language')) {
        Configure::write('Config.language', $this->Session->read('Config.language'));
        if ($this->Session->read('Config.language')=='spa')
            setlocale(LC_TIME, array('es_ES.UTF-8', 'esp'));
        else if ($this->Session->read('Config.language')=='ita')
            setlocale(LC_TIME, array('it_IT.UTF-8', 'ita'));
        else
            setlocale(LC_TIME, array('en_US.UTF-8', 'eng'));
        }
    }

}
```

and my languages controller stays simply like:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class IdiomasController extends AppController {

    var $uses = array();

    public function idioma_spa($u=null) 
    {
        $this->Session->write('Config.language', 'spa');
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }

    public function idioma_eng($u=null) 
    {
        $this->Session->write('Config.language', 'eng');
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }

    public function idioma_ita($u=null) 
    {
        $this->Session->write('Config.language', 'ita');
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
}
```

Don't know if its the most efficient way but works like a charm!